# Lightdm is broken when used ubuntu tweak to change the default background!

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm, desktop-background

I have ubuntu 14.04 and I used the "change login screen background" and now, when I change my wallpaper, The wallpaper on the login screen dose not change and if I change it via ubuntu tweak, The wallpaper breaks and just shows a purple screen and when I login, some part of the screen changes into statc and other things. How do I fix this?
Thank you people for all your support

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem other day, i fix this with dpkg-reconfigure

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

I also changed to default wallpaper in Ubuntu Tweak before doing this.